# How do you escape escaped text in HTML?

Tags: html

I'm working on a technical document where I'm escaping `(` and `)` with `&#40;` and `&#41;` in the example code I'm displaying.  I need to be able to show the readers the escaped version of the character so they can follow along in their own code, but it escapes into the character it's intended to represent.  How can I prevent it from doing this so the reader can see `&#40;` and `&#41;` rather than `(` and `)`?

Comment: You want to escape the `&`, to rob it of its special meaning in this instance.

Comment: Use espaced `&`: `&amp;#40;`